# Restoring files with 255+ character pathnames + Server 2000

Tags: restore, trueimage

I'm experiencing an issue when trying to restore files that have filename paths over 255 characters (in that they will not restore).

The file server is Server 2000 (ancient, I know) and the software is Acronis True Image Server 9. I've tried the "recovery" feature as well as mounting the image as a logical drive and copying and pasting to a shorter path (with no luck).

Can anyone offer me some advice here? Are these files gone for good or do I have a hope of getting them back?

**EDIT / UPDATE : I was successfully able to restore these files on a Windows XP machine...it seems as though the issue was/is with my Server 2000 machine and NOT True Image.**

Comment: Just a side note, but server 2000 isn't just ancient, it's also unsupported.  Microsoft no longer releases new security patches for windows 2000, and so any flaws discovered in the OS since July 13 of this year are still wide open.

Answer (score 0):

[There are ways to work around the Windows path length limitation](https://serverfault.com/questions/163419/window-256-characters-path-name-limitation), but you'd have to convince the Acronis software to use one of them. Maybe you could restore deeply nested files in a different location and move them in place afterwards. Or you could use another program to restore the files, if you find another program that understands the format used by Acronis.

For a backup program, creating backups that it can't restore is a major bug. I suggest you contact Acronis support.

Comment: Restoring the deeply nested files to another location has not worked. If I had to do that I would be much less concerned about this.

Oddly enough I can c&p the files from the file server share themself on my WinXP workstation. These, however, are the live files and thus this does me no good in the case where I would need to restore them in an emergency.